# make a local web server with WIFI?

Tags: matlab, wifi, wampserver

i have my computer have matlab and wamp server on it
i have a website run on the server
the website is a image processing application which is a php page that call a matlab m file and do processing on image that is sent to that php page
i can access my website by simply type

```
http://localhost/compute.php
```

what i want is to make a wireless network , so any device connected to this network can access that hyperlink

```
http://localhost/compute.php
```

, the device that access it is android phone that will take  a picture and directly send it to a specified server which is

```
http://localhost/compute.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly : instead of using **localhost** in your URL you should use your "internal" IP.

For example :

```
http://192.168.0.100/compute.php
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your system ip address like if your system ip 192.168.1.56 and using android device and networks url as below like

```
http://192.168.1.56/compute.php
```

that's means

```
http://yoursystemipaddress/compute.php
```

Comment: what is the way to do that ?

Comment: your just connected all devices on your network(start the wampserver.)and open browser on android device or system type the url like replace localhost as your system ip ok?

Answer (score 1):

If the connected device is within the local network then you should be able to replace `localhost` with the IP Address of the computer which is running your web server.

For example, if your webserver is running on `192.168.1.128` then you can use the URL `http://192.168.1.128/compute.php`, then if you are able to `PING 192.168.1.128` from the other device then you will also be able to access the web server.

Comment: ok , if i make an adhoc network with connectify in windows
will that work ?